# Python get form request

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, header, token

I am trying to figure out how to get a form var from a get request, but I can not figure out how to do so.

Code snippet:

```
        url = "webpage" 
        s = requests.Session()
        getheaders = {'Accept': '*/*','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko','Pragma': 'no-cache'}

        login = s.get(url, headers=getheaders)
        #here i want to get the form somehow
        #token = s.get.form['token'] #?
        #print(token)
```

I am unsure how to proceed after the get request to extract the var.

Comment: I my be confused by your terminology, but it seems to me like there may be a basic  misunderstanding on your part. I think are asking how to get access to the arguments specified in a GET request, but you *are* the one making the request - the *client* in this interaction. Access to GET data is something you do in the *server* that processes requests. the `requests` package you are using is not meant for this kind of operations.

Comment: oh,there is a token generated for each request its made,so i want to get the token of a request and then uses it like an auth on the post request,im sure im missunderstanding something but i dont know

Comment: To be exact, there is a token when u make the get and its written on the text i just want to extract the token and save is as a str                            <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="